# DTD Qualifiers - difference between placing them inside or outside the parentheses

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm a writing a DTD for an XML document that has `<students>` as its root element and may contain 0+ `<student>` elements.

What is the difference between declaring

```
<!ELEMENT students (student)*>
```

and

```
<!ELEMENT students (student+)>
```

They are both validating.

Comment: They're identical... did you mean to post different definitions?

Comment: Ooops my bad! Thanks Jim. I updated it

Comment: It seems like they really only make a difference in a case lie `<!ELEMENT release-date (#PCDATA|year)*>` where you want the qualifier to apply to everything in the brackets but not just one thing. Can someone verify that is the only difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content model `(student)*` accepts zero or more `student` elements; the content model `(student+)` accepts one or more.

The OP is correct in his conjectural comment about when it matters whether the occurrence indicator is inside or outside the parentheses.

Occurrence indicators attached to a name (as in `(student+)`) apply to elements of that name.  Occurrence indicators attached to a parenthesized group (as in `(student)*`) apply to the group as a whole.  When the parenthesized group contains only one token, as in these cases, the position of the occurrence indicator has no effect.  So `(student+)` and `(student)+` mean the same thing, as do the corresponding pair with asterisk instead of plus.

When the group contains multiple tokens, the position of the indicator does make a difference:  `(a | b)+` accepts any non-empty sequence of intermixed `a` and `b` elements, while `(a+ | b+)` accepts either a non-empty sequence of `a` elements or a non-empty sequence of `b` elements, but no mixtures.  (Some learners have trouble with this, but it's worth learning.)  Similarly, `(a, b)+` and `(a+, b+)` define two different languages.